# How to print content of scrollable control

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I was wondering what is the best way to print entire content of scrollable control. I was trying to print a control in several ways, however all the time I was only able to draw visible content of control. So far I tried to use

```
PrintForm // there is nothing I can do with this because it requires a form not a control
```

I was also trying to use `controlName.DrawToBitmap()` method however this function captures only the visible area of control.
What is the best way to draw this kind of controls ?? I would like to avoid scrolling control's content in order to capture all control's element.

Comment: This isn't going to work.  Use PrintDocument.

Comment: @HansPassant How PrintDocument will help ?? I must somehow pass control's content to printing. I used this component before however I wasn't able to pass entiere control's content to be printed.

Comment: Well, what's in the control?  Do try to document your question better.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create an invisible to the end-user form (for examlpe, position it at (-10000, -10000) and this form should have the size enough to display the ScrollableControl without scrollbars.  This way you will be able to workaround this problem.

Comment: I've tried this solution, however adding control to form (the invisible for user one) requires to remove this control from current form (form visible for user). So the user probably will see some flicering or something like that during printing or preparation for print

Comment: Create a new instance of the same form and populate it with data.  In this case, there won't be flickering when you need to print the form.